# How to import client provided .Cer certificate file in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, ssl-certificate, restful-authentication, client-certificates

I am using Rest Api to make calls to the https domain and salesforce is giving me 
**System.CalloutException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching certificate found**

So I asked for certificate from Cleint. Client provided us with .CER certificate files. How will i use them? I converted them to JKS using Java KeyTool but all in vain.

Comment: Are you providing SSO Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Certificate import in salesforce to be used with named credentials/ callouts , only supports .jks file extensions.You need to ask your certificate provider to give one in .jks.

Answer (score -1):

You can import certificate in Salesforce Panel.

**Setup->Security Controls->Certificate and Key Management**

Comment: Its for importing Java Key Store. There is no provision to import .cer

Comment: @susanoochidori if you are providing SSO then you will gets this in SAML Single Sign-On Setting page.

Comment: No i am not ussing SSO. I just wanna import my certificate so that i can make calls via code.